# Printing out each line of a text file in Java that only contains a specific String?

Tags: java, text, filter, full-text-search, bufferedreader

I'm a bit of a beginner to OOP and was wondering if I could some help on this issue.

How would I go about writing some code that would read each line of a text file, and then only print out each line of the textfile that contains a certain bit of string.

So, for example, lets imagine I have a example.txt file with the following contents:

```
OK Print this Line;
OK Print this Line;
NO Do not Print this Line;
OK Print this Line;
NO Do not Print this Line;
```

Is there anyway to get Java to print out only the lines with the string "OK" in it, and do so in a similar format? (So with newline breaks). So I would want Java to print this out:

```
OK Print this Line;
OK Print this Line;
OK Print this Line;
```

I've been scouring the internet and trying to think of some ways to do this, but I'm really stuck. Is it possible to do this?

Thanks in advance - if you need any more information, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: The best I've managed to do is put all the contents of the file into a String (and I managed to put it a LinkedList too....for whatever that is worth). I can then search that String for specific characters using the substring command, which works for finding specific parts of the document. I'm stuck after that.

Comment: You're making it much more difficult than it needs to be. There's no need to use a LinkedList or to read the whole file in before working on it. Simply read in each line, decide if you should print it, and print it. That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to break the problem down into steps. For instance:

- Figure out how to read each line of text in a file. A Scanner object will work nicely for this and you can find the [Scanner API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) at the link I've provided. Look at using a while loop, Scanner's `hasNextLine()` and `nextLine()` method to get you going.
- Figure out how to see if the String obtained above *contains* "OK". There's a nice String method that the [String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) will help you with.
- Figure out how to print the line if it passes the above test. An if block will help here. I think that you already know how to use `System.out.println(...)`
- When done, dispose of the Scanner, tidy up...
- And voilà, there it is!

Comment: Thanks! I'll get to this. I've gotta go off to sleep for now but I'll dedicate my day tomorrow to doing this :)

Comment: Managed to do it really easily! (at least compared to how I was doing attempting it before). Thanks for giving good advice and not just the answer.

Comment: @oOTesterOo: way to go! I knew you could do it without our showing you!

Comment: @DeaIss can you update your original question to show how you implemented it?